# Excel lookup/find

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

Here is some example data:

[image: Excel Screen Shot]

What I am trying to do:

I have a second data sheet (shown below).

[image: Second Data Sheet].

I then need to somehow match the second data sheet from the first. Meaning, I want to look up/find "Adam, Joe" and then return "Adam Joe" from A1 in the first picture. Naturally this had way more people in it, but this is an example I used.

With over 300 people, I'm not sure of a quick way (My VLOOKUP didnt work).

Another example using the same data. 
Looking up Adam, Bob (from the second image/data), then I would need it to return whats in the first picture A1 ~ "Adam Joe"

Thanx guys!

Comment: I should also add:
Adam Joe may not always be in the first (or A1) line. But if it finds whats in the same row, i'd want it to tell me what A1 was (account holder)

Comment: What I have been able to do is this:
=INDEX(A1:J3,MATCH(E7,I:I,0),1)

Basically it only does 1 row at a time. I can't seem to match them all at once (ie. 1 Formula that works in all lines)


So that would only look in "Gala Kid 1", gives me Adam Joe. Then I'd need another line to look up Gala kid 2...

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern is consistent, you could use:

```
=vlookup(substitute(A1,",",""),'referenceData'!A1:L100,1,false)
```

Or, a better solution, looking at your input data, you have a column that matches the data you want, so you should use index and match

```
=index('referenceData'!A1:L100,match(A1,'referenceData'!G1:G100,0),1)
```

Where referenceData is your top table, and A1 is your "Adam, Joe" reference, and the end row is arbitrary, replace it with the actual end of your data

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/TzUvvbC.png

https://i.imgur.com/Rd7laP0.png

I have attached 2 images with better examples (I hope). Not sure if this helps?

Comment: So, if I've got your requirement correct, you want to look along MULTIPLE cells in each row, to find a match, and then return the value from the first cell in the Row?

Comment: Yep! I somewhat worked it out...

=IFNA(INDEX(Master!A:L,MATCH(C2,Gala_Kid_1,0),1),IFNA(INDEX(Master!A:L,MATCH(C2,Gala_Kid_2,0),1),IFNA(INDEX(Master!A:L,MATCH(C2,Official_2,0),1),INDEX(Master!A:L,MATCH(C2,Official_1,0),1))))